# NBA API endpoint with parameter not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, endpoint

I've been using the nba.com stats api and when I'm using the endpoint

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboard/?GameDate=02/14/2015&LeagueID=00&DayOffset=0
```

and can run it in a ruby script just fine. However when I try to access the other endpoints like `boxscoreplayertrackv2` with one parameter `'GameID'`, after I try to use the url

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreplayertrackv2/?GameID=00
```

I receive this message in my terminal

> "The field GameID must match the regular expression '^\d{10}$' ".

The api im using is

https://github.com/seemethere/nba_py/wiki/stats.nba.com-Endpoint-Documentation

Can't find anything on stackoverflow and also am quite a newb with ruby. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: question has nothing to do with ruby

Answer (score 0):

You do need to provide a valid GameId for this endpoint.  The game IDs are 10 digits.

So for GameId '0021301217' the call would look like this

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreplayertrackv2/?GameID=0021301217
```